# SQL Server Round hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I need to rounding time near 30 minutes.

This is an example:

1 minute -> 0,02 hours -> 0,5 hours

35 minutes -> 0.8 hours -> 1 hour

Comment: Why is 1 minute "rounded" to 0.5 hours when it's clearly *nearest* to 0 hours?

Comment: @Larnu can only guess biling .. you pay for every half an hour started.

Comment: My question is more on the fact that the OP says "rounding time near 30 minutes", which reads as broken English for the "nearest 30 minutes", @Kaii .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CEILING()` (or `CEIL()`, for other DBMS) to round up:

```
SELECT CEILING(1  / 30.0)*30   --> 30 minutes
SELECT CEILING(25 / 30.0)*30  --> 30 minutes
SELECT CEILING(35 / 30.0)*30  --> 60 minutes
```

or if you prefer hours:

```
SELECT CEILING(1  / 30.0)*30 / 60 --> 0.5 hour
SELECT CEILING(25 / 30.0)*30 / 60 --> 0.5 hour
SELECT CEILING(35 / 30.0)*30 / 60 --> 1 hour
```

Comment: `CEIL` isn't a built-in T-SQL function. Do you mean `CEILING`? Also, integer maths is not going to result in the values you want here. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/80Ds4nnh)

Comment: When you divide and integer by an integer then the result will be an integer.  So 1/30 = 0 even with ceiling.  You need e.g. CEILING(1/30.0) * 30

Comment: @Wouter thx. I checked with another RDBMS and you are right, MS SQL is more picky when it comes to arithmetics. Corrected and tested my answer in T-SQL.

Comment: In truth, I think *most* (R)DBMS will not implicitly convert an `integer` datatype to a `numeric`/`float` value when using division, @Kaii , as strong data typing in such things is important. You'll often find the same behaviour in other languages where the data type has to explicitly defined, such as in C#, Java, and Go.

Comment: @Larnu you are right. Only MySQL/MariaDB implicitly return float when dividing int by int. I just checked several DBMS.

Comment: With this "CAST(CEILING((@var)*2)/2 AS DECIMAL(8,1))" it's work,